# ScriptControl inside UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scriptmanager, scriptcontrol

I have a `ScriptControl` (requires `ScriptManager`) with JavaScript to handle client-side interactions and `ICallbackEventHandler` to communicate back and forth.  Everything works perfectly with one or multiple instances of the control on a page.  I placed the control inside a `GridView` with sorting and it still works.  However, I place the `GridView` in an `UpdatePanel` and now whenever I sort I get the following error for each instance:

`Sys.InvalidOperationException: Two components with the same id 'GridView_ctl02_MyControl' can't be added to the application.`

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?  I am assuming `ScriptManager` is not disposing of the old `Sys.UI.Control` objects before trying to `$create()` the new ones with the same ID.  I thought the `UpdatePanel`/`ScriptManager` combination would automatically take care of disposing objects that would be replaced?

**Edit:** This page appears to support what I thought: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerdispose.aspx

> Use the RegisterDispose method to
>   register dispose scripts for controls
>   that are inside an UpdatePanel
>   control. During asynchronous
>   postbacks, UpdatePanel controls can be
>   updated, deleted, or created. **When a
>   panel is updated or deleted, any
>   dispose scripts that are registered
>   for controls that are inside the
>   UpdatePanel are called. In typical
>   page development scenarios, you do not
>   have to call the RegisterDispose
>   method.**

Just to double check I placed an `alert("dispose " + this.element.id)` inside my JavaScript `dispose()` function.  Every single instance alerts `dispose GridView_ctl02_MyControl`, but afterwards I get the error that two components can't have the same name `GridView_ctl02_MyControl`.  I'm at a loss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page unloads, my component's `dispose()` method is called and `Sys.Application.removeComponent()` is also called.  When the `UpdatePanel` reloads, only `dispose()` method is called.  For now I have solved this by putting `Sys.Application.removeComponent(this);` inside the `dispose()`.  I didn't find a shortcut such as $remove (similar to $create), implying you aren't expected to need this often.

This seems logical in that you can keep a component loaded even after its related DOM elements (if any) have been replaced by the UpdatePanel.  This way you have more control over the component's life.  I can't imagine a use case, but I'm sure you could come up with one.

If I am way off and there is a better approach, please let me know!